# How to change VSCode search highlight color

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm searching for something in VSCode
[image]

and highlight the search [image]

the text is not readable anymore.
Is it possible to only change this highlight background?

If yes, what is the required variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your Settings in JSON format

[image]

and add the below property to the main object

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "selection.background": "#202020"
}
```

Here `#202020` is a shade of black. You can use the color code of your choice.

Refer [Base Colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#base-colors) for all the base color properties and [Input-Control](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#input-control) for all the input control specific properties.

Additional Reference: [Customizing Color Theme - Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme)

Answer (score 0):

That was just the hint I needed to sort out what I wanted. I liked the Monokai Dimmed, but the Find All in a file colours just made the text illegible. I also used the alpha (transparency) channel  so ended up with:

[image]

The settings.json ended up containing:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai Dimmed]": {
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#9c9c783c",
        "editor.findMatchBackground": "#fbfbbf"
    }
}
```